# Google Drive SDK - Drive Scopes

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to use this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

Which is the Google drive SDK for Android.

I want to be able to list all files in a users Google drive account.  But only access is given to files and folders that the app created (or that the user selects).

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

Can Google Devs tell me if it is possible to List a users files and folders with this SDK, and retrieve metadata?  Only SCOPE_FILE access is permitted.

If not, will more access be given in the future?

I have tried (and failed miserably) to use the Java Library but I cannot get it to work.  So hopefully I can find out of the new SDK will include other permissions (which the Java library does).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My solution is use [google-http-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client) library and [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) library instead of google drive SDK for Android. The main benefit is that you can access all the files on the Google drive. below is a section code to create the Drive object in code, then you can use this object to access the files.

```
            final GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .addRefreshListener(refreshListener)
                .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret).build()
                .setRefreshToken(refreshToken).setAccessToken(accessToken);

        // Create a new authorized API client
        final Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                credential).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, currently only SCOPE_FILE is available on Android. Users much prefer that you have this scope, so that they can control which files your app accesses.  You should be able to use the provided user interfaces to allow your users to browse all of the files and pick the one they want to use with your app. See [OpenFileActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#newOpenFileActivityBuilder%28%29).

Comment: Thanks Cheryl - but ideally I would like a user to select a folder using the folder picker.  And then be able to list all the files inside that folder in a custom ListView. I want my user to be able to multi select whchever item in the list they wish. This is not possible currently - unless I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Cheryl - hopefully you can respond to my query.  Hopefully this can be achieved using the SDK.

Comment: Is this at all possible with the Android SDK?

Comment: No, there is not currently a way to get access to an entire tree of contents without the user explicitly authorizing each.

Comment: Thanks Cheryl.  I was hoping that the permissions could change so that if a user selects a folder using the FolderPicker, then it is assumed that they want to see the contents of that folder and it would authorize everything in that folder.  Is this a reasonable request and something that could be changed>?

Comment: or else add a read-only permission where the android app can read metadata from all files and folders.

Comment: Is there a definitive answer to this question? Will there ever be https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope on Android SDK?