# How can get list of files from Google Drive to my app?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm making an app that'll allows me to get a google drive files to my app. I have managed to open the google drive and to download a file to my phone but that's not the point to this app. I'm trying to open the files from the app, not to open the Google Drive. Any help?
Note: I've already registered my app at Google cloud console and all of the stuff there.

Here's the code. But as i said i don't need to open the Google Drive, i need to get files from there in my app.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            // disconnect Google API client connection
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

        if (!result.hasResolution()) {

            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
 try {

            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    public void onClickCreateMethod(View view){
        fileOperation = true;

        // create new contents resource
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);

    }

    public void onClickOpenFileMethod(View view){
        fileOperation = false;

        // create new contents resource
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }

    /**
     *  Open list of folder and file of the Google Drive
     */
    public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive(){

        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(

                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }

    }
final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {

                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        if (fileOperation == true) {

                            CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(result);

                        } else {

                            OpenFileFromGoogleDrive();

                        }
                    }

                }
            };
public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result){

        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello abhay!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("abhaytest2")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file in root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file created: "+""+
                                result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    return;

                }
            };
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                    final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + "");

                    String url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + mFileId.getResourceId();
                    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(url);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);

                    DriveFile googleDriveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, driveId);
                    DriveResource.MetadataResult mdRslt = googleDriveFile.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                        if(mdRslt!= null && mdRslt.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                            mdRslt.getMetadata().getTitle();
                                System.out.println("The title is : " + driveId);

                        }
 }

                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }

    public Context getAppContext() {
        return appContext;
    }
```

Comment: Would you like to show a [mcve] of what you have so far?

Comment: public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive(){                                           intentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    } The code is too long to to be shown, but here's the method where i'm oppening drive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code.

Comment: FILE scope will give you access to files opened by your app.
To see all the files you'll need to use the Drive Scope.
Unfortunately, the Android Drive API does not support the Drive Scope.
You can use the Drive REST API though. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341776/google-drive-sdk-drive-scopes