# Trouble with google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to create an application for browsing all files in google drive that are located in root folder. The problem is I can set up permissions only for creating and browsing files. But I have to browse the files which I upload in google drive via browser.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

Comment: FILE scope will give you access to files opened by your app.
To see all the files you'll need to use the Drive Scope.
Unfortunately, the Android Drive API does not support the Drive Scope.
You can use the Drive REST API though. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341776/google-drive-sdk-drive-scopes

Comment: do you still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve files from the `root folder` use [`Drive.getRootFolder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi#getRootFolder(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) method.

The getRootFolder will returns a `DriveFolder` and it can be used to interact with the root folder. This method will return synchronously, and is safe to invoke from the UI thread.

```
DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
folder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient())
.setResultCallback(metadataResult);
```

public static final [Scope](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope) `SCOPE_FILE` a Scope that gives 'drive.file' access to a user's drive. This scope give per-file access to files that have been created by, or specifically opened with the app.

The `Scope` implements `SafeParcelable` which describes an OAuth 2.0 scope to request. This has security implications for the user, and requesting additional scopes will result in authorization dialogs.

Here's a sample demo app, demo app illustrates all possible ways to talk to Drive service with the use of interfaces available in Google Play Services: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/